# HTML contact form, PHP code

Tags: php, html, forms

I was trying to send multiple vars from my html form to my email by using PHP. The problem is that I do not know anything about PHP. I found a simple form which worked for me, but it contained only 3 vars, subject, email and message. This time however I have 7.

Here's the code.

```
<?php

$projectname = htmlentities($_POST['projectname']);
$projectemail = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projectemail']));
$projectphone = htmlentities($_POST['projectphone']);
$projectcompany = htmlentities($_POST['projectcompany']);
$projecttype = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projecttype']));
$projecttimeline = htmlentities($_POST['projecttimeline']);
$aboutproject = htmlentities($_POST['aboutproject']);

$message = "{$projectname}{$projectphone}{$projectcompany}{$projecttimeline}{$aboutproject}";


$subject = $projecttype;
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';

$body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

$headers = "From: $projectemail\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);


header('Location: thanks.html');
?>
```

And the corresponding HTML

```
<form id="formproject" action="thank_you_project.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="projectname" name="name">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="projectemail" name="email">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="projectphone" name="phone">

<label for="company">Company</label>
<input type="text" id="projectcompany" name="company">

<label for="typeofproject">Type of project</label>
<input type="text" id="projecttype" name="typeofproject">

<label for="timeline">Timeline</label>
<input type="text" id="projecttimeline" name="timeline">

<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="aboutproject" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="projectsend" value="Send"></input>
</form>

</div> <!-- end form -->
```

Edited the PHP, left out the body and put message in mail instead, still not working.

```
<?php

$projectname = htmlentities($_POST['projectname']);
$projectemail = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projectemail']));
$projectphone = htmlentities($_POST['projectphone']);
$projectcompany = htmlentities($_POST['projectcompany']);
$projecttype = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projecttype']));
$projecttimeline = htmlentities($_POST['projecttimeline']);
$aboutproject = htmlentities($_POST['aboutproject']);

$message = "{$projectname}{$projectphone}{$projectcompany}{$projecttimeline}{$aboutproject}";


$subject = $projecttype;
$to = 'albermy145@alberttomasiak.be';


$headers = "From: $projectemail\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


header('Location: thanks.html');
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$projectname = htmlentities($_POST['projectname']);
$projectemail = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projectemail']));
$projectphone = htmlentities($_POST['projectphone']);
$projectcompany = htmlentities($_POST['projectcompany']);
$projecttype = trim(strip_tags($_POST['projecttype']));
$projecttimeline = htmlentities($_POST['projecttimeline']);
$aboutproject = htmlentities($_POST['aboutproject']);
$header  = "From: $projectemail \r\n";
$subject = $projecttype;
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your HTML</p>
Project Name : $projectname
<br/>
Project Email : $projectemail
<br/>
Project Phone : $projectphone
...
...
...
...
</body>
</html>
";
$message .= "";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($retval == true)  
{
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();
}
?>
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="formproject" action="thank_you_project.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="projectname" name="projectname">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="projectemail" name="projectemail">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="projectphone" name="projectphone">

<label for="company">Company</label>
<input type="text" id="projectcompany" name="projectcompany">

<label for="typeofproject">Type of project</label>
<input type="text" id="projecttype" name="projecttype">

<label for="timeline">Timeline</label>
<input type="text" id="projecttimeline" name="projecttimeline">

<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea name="aboutproject" id="aboutproject" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="projectsend" value="Send"></input>
</form>

</div> <!-- end form -->
```

Comment: When I use this code I get sent to a blank page, and I receive an email that there was a failure sending because of no recipient. :/

Comment: Sorry, need to add *$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';*

Comment: I tried your method, but now when I receive the mail I only get the strings (like Project Name : ) and no subject nor recipient :/ I dont know what's wrong I looked at the PHP and the HTML in hope that I'll spot some kind of mistake but I couldnt find anything

Comment: I tried and received perfectly. Subject as *$subject = $projecttype;* and recipient as *$header  = "From: $projectemail \r\n";*.

Answer (score 0):

Add all variables into `$body` (which is the third param of `mail` function).

```
//$body = <<<HTML
//$message <br>
//$projectname <br>
//$projectcompany<br>
//...
//HTML;
```

Or the second way is to add these vars into the third mail param directly.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
// this code is updated as I wrote in my comment below.
```

Comment: So it isn't enough if I put all variables into message and then only post message in the body?

Comment: You put them into `$body` (my first code snippet), or directly to `mail` function (2nd snippet). Both will work (I use only two variables to show you how to, you need to add others too).

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll definetely try it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see `$message` in your question before. In this case you don't need to create and use `$body` and put `$message` mail function. I updated code in my answwer. If it works correctly, I leave this updated solution in my answer only.

Comment: If I leave out the body and put message in the mail I just get an empty mail after I fill in all the fields and send them in. Just to be sure, here's the php. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

the form posted the value of input is using 'name' attribute as identifier of value,

```html
<form id="formproject" action="thank_you_project.php" method="post">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectname" name="name">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectemail" name="email">

    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectphone" name="phone">

    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" id="projectcompany" name="company">

    <label for="typeofproject">Type of project</label>
    <input type="text" id="projecttype" name="typeofproject">

    <label for="timeline">Timeline</label>
    <input type="text" id="projecttimeline" name="timeline">

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="aboutproject" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="projectsend" value="Send"></input>
</form>

<!-- end form -->   

    <?php
        $projectname = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        $projectemail = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $projectphone = htmlentities($_POST['phone']);
        $projectcompany = htmlentities($_POST['company']);
        $projecttype = trim(strip_tags($_POST['typeofproject']));
        $projecttimeline = htmlentities($_POST['timeline']);
        $aboutproject = htmlentities($_POST['message']);
    ?>
```